# First community-goal earns credits or reputation?

Tags: elite-dangerous

The first community goal is running since the last update. I wonder whether I'll earn credits or "just" reputation if I - in this case - deliver metals to the new to-be-built station.
Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The award for a community goal is credits, plus a discount (depends on the goal, but this can be outfitting, or on ships etc).

So, for the community goal to build a station, it got to tier 4, and I was in the top 40%. This meant I got 50,000Cr bonus (on top of the good price for selling metals to the station anyway), and a discount for a limited time on ships and outfitting. Unfortunately, there wasn't much I needed that was available at the station for outfitting, or ships higher than my current T7, so I made no use of this.

No doubt the awards will change depending on the goal, but ultimately you get a bonus on top of the money you make on trading, exploring or combat (depending on the type of community goal you do).

So far the commuity goals have been

- build a station (trade metals)
- fight in a war zone for the federation (combat)
- help expand cartographies (exploration)